# Validate package against repository

Tags: apt, package-management

In the light of the recent vulnerability in the `apt` package manager - how do I check that `apt` itself is valid? I see with `apt --version` that the version is the newest one with the fix, but what if apt itself is compromised?

I've found info on `debsums`, but it checks files against the md5 sums stored locally **during the installation**, so it's rather an integrity check.

Can I check against the actual ubuntu repository?

Comment: This particular question has already been addressed in depth by the [Ubuntu Security Team's podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/episode-18/).

Comment: Sorry, I've listened to the podcast but couldn't find the answer to the question. They discuss how the vulnerability works, using https to mitigate MiTM attacks, and come to the conclusion that if you don't trust the mirror then you're screwed anyway. But how do I validate my locally installed `apt` without using apt?

Comment: Assuming that I do trust the mirror, how do I check that the version of apt I have installed at the moment, is not already compromised

Comment: If you trust the mirror, then are you asking how to verify (the lack of) an MiTM attack? Or are you asking how to audit the source code?

Comment: Imagine that before the issue was fixed, there was an MiTM attack and the `apt` currently installed on my system is hacked. When I do `apt --version` it may output correct version number but in reality some of the binaries used by apt are fake. When I do `apt-get --reinstall...` it just outputs good-looking garbage but does nothing. Now if I go on ubuntu official website, I can find apt package, and the list of files (e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/apt/filelist) but there are no checksums there, so I can't validate my local files against this list. Can I?